# Is there a policy definition language for GraphQL APIs?

Tags: graphql

Is there a way for us to define the policies of a GraphQL API, which is both machine-readable and human-readable, which contains a set of rules (in other words, a specification) to describe the format of the API? I'm not talking about the schema, but of a spec where we can add security-related details (for example, complexity value to be assigned per field and depth limitation values) or any other related details. Any thoughts or ideas? Or can we send all of this within the SDL itself?

For example, for REST APIs, we use Swagger to define information on how to define paths, parameters, responses, models, security and more. Is there a need for a similar approach for GraphQL APIs? Your response is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working in an approach to add policies to your GraphQL API and allow you to better manage it, especially as you expose the interface externally.

Part of the challenge is that as opposed to a REST call that can easily be differentiated from others, all GraphQL requests look the same, unless a deeper analysis is performed on the incoming query.

This blog post describes how we perform this analysis: https://www.ibm.com/blogs/research/2019/02/graphql-api-management/

if this is of interest let's connect!

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes, this is similar to what I was asking about, where we perform a more fine-grained access control to a graphql request by doing deeper analysis of the query. Although, the policies I have in mind are somewhat different from what's suggested in the blog post. But definitely we can connect over the 2 approaches. I will shortly write a blog with the idea that I have suggested, I will share the link when I do.

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding you need a tool to make documentation for the APIs you have build for parameters and so on. 
If that's what you are searching, there is like swagger for GraphQL - [Swagger-to-GraphQL](https://github.com/yarax/swagger-to-graphql)

Hope that helps.!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not what I was talking about. I want to know if there is a way for us to define security-related details (allowed max depth value, complexity limitation details) for a GraphQL API. What you have suggested is a way to convert a swagger schema to a GraphQL schema, but I already have a GraphQL schema. Maybe something to define security-related details would do (something new for graphql, just like swagger is for REST).